# sql finding gaps in a couple number/year

Tags: sql, select, self-join

I have a table like:

```
id
number 
year
```

I want to find "holes", or gaps, not considering the id but only the couple year/number.

There is a gap when, for the same year, there are two non-consecutive numbers, the result being the year and all the numbers between (excluding extremes) those two non-consecutive numbers. Also note that **the lower end is always 1** so that if 1 is missing, it is a gap.

For example, having:

```
id  n   year
1   1   2012   
2   2   2012
3   5   2012
4   2   2010
```

I want as a result:

```
3/2012
4/2012
1/2010
```

Comment: Is there a maximum `n`? What if the last `n` is missing?

Comment: What DBMS are you using?

Comment: @biziclop number is a `NUMBER(9)`. What do you mean with last n missing? It can't be missing: if there's only a number for a given year, then that is the end of the range, the start always being 1. If a year has no records it's fine.

Comment: @GarethD I'm using Oracle but I think it's not important because I'm looking for a standard SQL query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The trick to finding missing entries in sequences is to generate a cartesian product of all available combinations in the sequence, then use `NOT EXISTS` to elimate those that exist. This is hard to do in a non DBMS specific way because all have different ways in which to optmially create a sequence on the fly. For Oracle I use:

```
SELECT  RowNum AS r
FROM    Dual
CONNECT BY Level <= MaxRequiredValue;
```

So, to generate a list of all available year/n pairs I would use:

```
SELECT  d.Year, n.r
FROM    (   SELECT  year, MAX(n) AS MaxN 
            FROM    T 
            GROUP BY Year
        ) d
        INNER JOIN
        (   SELECT  RowNum AS r
            FROM    Dual
            CONNECT BY Level <= (SELECT MAX(n) FROM T)
        ) n
            ON r < MaxN;
```

Where I am getting the Maximum n for each year and joining this to a list of integers from 1 to the highest n of all where this integer lists highest value is less than that years maximium value.

Finally use `NOT EXISTS` to elimate the values that already exist:

```
SELECT  d.Year, n.r
FROM    (   SELECT  year, MAX(n) AS MaxN 
            FROM    T 
            GROUP BY Year
        ) d
        INNER JOIN
        (   SELECT  RowNum AS r
            FROM    Dual
            CONNECT BY Level < (SELECT MAX(n) FROM T)
        ) n
            ON r = MaxN
WHERE   NOT EXISTS
        (   SELECT  1
            FROM    T
            WHERE   d.Year = t.Year
            AND     n.r = t.n
        );
```

Working example on **[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/b6e1d/24)**

---

**EDIT**

Since I couldn't find a non DMBS specific solution I thought I'd better do the decent thing and create some examples for other DBMS.

[SQL Server Example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/22eb0/2)

[Postgresql Example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!1/22eb0/4)

[My SQL Example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/22eb0/2)

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use a temporary table like so:

```
create table #tempTable ([year] int, n int)

insert 
into    #tempTable
select  t.year, 1
from    tableName t 
group by    t.year

while exists(
    select  *
    from    tableName t1
    where   t1.n > (select MAX(t2.n) from #tempTable t2 where t2.year = t1.year)
)
begin

    insert 
    into    #tempTable
    select  t1.year, 
        (select MAX(t2.n)+1 from #tempTable t2 where t2.year = t1.year)
    from    tableName t1
    where   t1.n > (select MAX(t2.n) from #tempTable t2 where t2.year = t1.year)

end

delete  t2
from    #tempTable t2
inner join  tableName t1
on  t1.year = t2.year
and t1.n = t2.n

select  [year], n
from    #tempTable

drop table  #tempTable
```